# In `Representational State Transfer`, What does `State Transfer` exactly mean?

Tags: api, rest, web-services, http, client-server

I am getting confused because of multiple views on the terms state transfer in REST

But what exactly state transfer means in REST?

Is it something like... If the resource is `Weather report of NEWYORK STATE` then each time it changes but when a client requests the server for `the report of NY`, it transfers the `representation of that resource at the current STATE` (I MEAN THE WEATHER AT THE CURRENT time?)

Or

Is it something like FORMAT OF THE RESOURCE in SERVER AND CLIENT? (I mean.. If the RESOURCE is a PNG IMAGE MAY BE BLOB FORMAT in DB(server-side) but to the clients, the format will be in PNG/JPG etc?) - if this is correct then it is just a representation right how we are saying it is state?

Comment: Hello, thank you for contributing to StackOverflow. Please note that still I downvoted your question as there exists already a huge amount of documentation on the Web about REST. Your question is also already answered on the first Google link (which might be Wikipedia - in the 'Statelessness' paragraph). Enjoy reading. Regards